# Excel VLOOKUP for 3 columns

Tags: excel

I'm going to use the VLOOKUP for 3 columns in my xls file. Below is the reference table :

```
Building     |    Floor    |     Location ID
----------------------------------------------
Building A   | 1           | 1001
Building A   | 2           | 1002
Building B   | Ground      | 2000
```

How should I write the VLOOKUP formula for this case ? So that I can use the `Building` and `Floor` columns as the **LOOKUP VALUE** and the `Location ID` as the **RESULT** ? Thx.

Comment: Looks like homework to me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the "right" way to do this, but I usually add another column that concatenates the cells I want to lookup separated by a "|" and then do the vlookup on that column.

```
Building|Floor    Building    Floor    LocationID
Building A|1      Building A  1        1001
....
```

Use something like this to get the concatenated values

```
=Concatenate(B2,"|",C2)
```

You can then do your vlookup like this:

```
=VLookup(Concatenate([buildingvalue],"|",[floorvalue]),A:D,4,false)
```

Comment: Well. Thx for this. This one really help @Greg

Comment: Stuff like this makes me love sql/databases

Answer (score 2):

Insert another column to combine `Building` and `Floor` (let assume in column `C`).  The `|` should be any character that won't appear in either `Building` or `Floor`

```
=A2&"|"&B2
```

Then `VLOOKUP` using this new column